# Code snippet paths in GCC

Tags: gcc, path, code-snippets

Background: Keil C51 on a PC, currently moving to GCC (CrossPack-AVR) on an iMac.

Since I write firmware for micro's I have a lot of 'driver' source files etc. that I need to include with my programs, e.g. a LCD driver, i.e. reusing code. These code snippets (.c and .h files) live sub folders in a    `/snippets/` folder, i.e.    `/snippets/lcd/`. My `/snippets/` used to be in a folder that also had a `/projects/` folder for, well, projects or applications. I had considered putting them in a library but I use various architectures so it would not always work.

The Question: How can one set that up in GCC without having to specify absolute paths to the snippets in, for example, the various `#include` paths etc. so that the source file, of the included snippet, gets re-compiled along with the project that uses/includes it? Thus, if I improve on a snippet, it benefits all projects that is compiled/re-compiled subsequently?

I looked around on google but must be using the wrong search term.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question right: You have snippets (.c) and corresponding include files (.h) and you want GCC to recompile changed snippets if their includes are included in the current project. Right?

Comment: I have a lot of c source files (& their associated h files) for various pieces of hardware (LCD's, DUART's, Keypads..) Each live in their own folder (/lcd /duart /keypad). All these are in a folder called /snippets which in turn is in a folder called /dev. Also in /dev there is a /projects folder.So, if I'm working on a project, e.g. robot, there will be a folder called /dev/projects/robot with files that make up the robot app. But, if the robot needs a LCD, how do I tell gcc to include /dev/snippets/lcd/lcd.h & lcd.c without specifying the absolute path, something like $SNIPPETPATH/lcd/lcd.h.

Answer (score 0):

I think make files will do the trick.